# Does 'Padre' mean 'friend' AND 'father'?

Tags: pronombres, parentesco

I've noticed in some Spanish related films, characters will refer to a Spanish character as `Padre` when addressing them. For example, in the *Mask Of Zorro*, one character refers to a stranger as `Padre` when he says [here](https://www.scripts.com/script.php?id=the_mask_of_zorro_13456&p=4):

> Where is he now, Padre, your masked friend?

But the stranger is not his father!

- So in what scenerio is it acceptable to call someone `padre`?
- Are the words `padre` and `amigo` interchangeable?
- How common is it to refer to someone (who is not your father) as `padre`?

Comment: No, padre is father, like your own father or a priest.

Comment: As mentioned by Lambie and gibianchi, in that context it's: "(often as a title or form of address) a priest. like in English. I think that amigo and padre are not interchangeable, at least in Spain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having, coincidentally, just watched the movie, i can confirm that the person in question is, in fact, a priest. Just like he might be adressed as *Father* in english, he is called *Padre* in spanish. (And the relationship of the speaker to the padre is not as a friend at all.)

Comment: haha, excellent, yeah I couldn't remember if he was referring to a priest or not. All makes sense now, thankyou :)

Answer (score 3):

I should listen to the part of the movie where the phrase appears, but it is most likely an abbreviation for "Compadre". If the person speaks in a fast way   it's most likely that he will eat the first syllable, so "compadre", normally used as a colleague/fella, becomes just *padre*. The use of the word *compadre* to address someone is common in people with little school education, so it's more than likely that there's an omission in part of the word.

Real meaning:

> Compadre: padrino de bautizo del hijo o del ahijado de una persona.

> Comadre: madrina de bautizo del hijo o del ahijado de una persona.

Colloquial use:

> Compadre / Comadre = Amigo/a del alma

Comment: could be referering to a priest also?

Comment: Good point. I didn't think about It. But I think the OP should have noticed this before asking.

Comment: "Spanish related films, characters will refer to a Spanish character as Padre when addressing them." dudoso ;) better ask OP?

Comment: compadre has no abbreviation. And this is taken from a movie script. So, they most likely mean priest i.e. father. I have never heard compadre shortened to padre.

Comment: Solo quiero aclarar que *compadre* sí tiene forma abreviada: *compa*.